# Copy an array if a specific column has a numeric values

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I would like to create the code, where I could copy the values in a certain array and paste only the values of that array to the column in front.
The arrays to be copied are in multiple arrays and should be copied and pasted to a column in front but only if there are numerical values in column A.

This is how the arrays with values (in yellow) look before the copy:
[image: Before]

And here is the outcome when they are pasted in the column in front (overwriting the rest):

[image: After]

My code is not working for many reasons and mainly I think there is the problem with my loops. The first loop should indicate that the copy will take place only on the rows where values in column A are numerical.

```
Sub Cop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set CopySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Const ColStart As Integer = 4 'Table to start copying
Const NewColStart As Integer = 3 'Table to start pasting
Const ColEnd As Integer = 10  'Table ends for copying and pasting
Const ColumnNumeric As Integer = 1 'Column with numbers
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range

TargetRow = 4   'Row where my table an column with numbers starts

With CopySheet
 For Each cell1 In Range(.Cells(TargetRow, ColumnNumeric), .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnNumeric))
        If IsNumeric(cell1) = True Then
        'Numeric value found. 
            For Each cell2 In Range(.Cells(TargetRow,ColStart),.Cells(.Rows.Count, ColEnd))
             cell2.Copy
            .Range(.Cells(TargetRow, NewColStart), .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColEnd)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False       
            Next cell2
            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1            
        Else
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next cell1
TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
End With
```

Can anybody give a hand on that? I was trying different loops but I am not sure how to finish them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Sub bellow

- Iterates through each cell with data in column A (`COL_NUMERIC`)
- If it contains a number (it doesn't contain an error and it's not empty)
- Dynamically determines the last column with data on the current row
- Copies the row with data (starting in Col D - `COL_START`) to an array
- Clears the data from the row
- Pastes the values from the array, one column to the left (it expects `COL_START` to be > 1)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MoveRowsLeft()

    Const COL_NUMERIC = 1
    Const ROW_START = 4
    Const COL_START = 4

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long
    Dim nCol As Range, itm As Range, r As Long, arr As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, COL_NUMERIC).End(xlUp).Row

    If lr > ROW_START Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set nCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(ROW_START, COL_NUMERIC), ws.Cells(lr, COL_NUMERIC))
        For Each itm In nCol
            If Not IsError(itm) Then
                If IsNumeric(itm) And Len(itm.Value2) > 0 Then
                    r = itm.Row
                    lc = ws.Cells(r, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    If lc > COL_NUMERIC Then
                        arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, COL_START), ws.Cells(r, lc))
                        ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, COL_START), ws.Cells(r, lc)).ClearContents
                        ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, COL_START - 1), ws.Cells(r, lc - 1)) = arr
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Super! Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. Many phrases I need to consider next time when creating the code.  Cheers

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Hi Paul, I have a small prblem with the code. It appears that when running, the code erases any content that is column 3, which is just in front of COL.Start. If I would like to keep some content in column 3, how can I prevent the code to erase the content in that column?